# How can I contains String value with map.key?

Tags: java, arrays, string, hashmap

I have massive of String

```
String[] mass = new String[]{"textp1","textp2tt","txtp3gfsdg","txtp4rfgsf"}//each element contains substring p1,p2,p3,p4
```

And

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("p1","blablabla");
map.put("p2","blablabla");
map.put("p3","blablabla");
map.put("p4","blablabla");
```

And I want contains each element of mass with key of map

```
for (String s : mass ) {
  if (s.contains(map.key)) form.setField(map.key,map.value);
 }
```

How can I realize this? Maby not Map?

I want method

```
public void method(String[] mass, Map<String, String> map){
for (String s : mass ) {
      if (s.contains(map.key)) form.setField(map.key,map.value);
     }
}
```

**EDIT**

I want create map like config and pass like parameter to method. I have some massives of String and I need parse it. cange only 1 parameter p1 or p999

Comment: Where is `form` defined?  I see it nowhere.

Answer (score 2):

As I can see, you're asking that for each String in your `mass` variable, is there any substring, which represents a key in `Map`

If that's the scenario, then you'd want to get multiple loops, one to iterate over your `String` and another to iterate over the your `Map`.

```
for (String s : mass ) {        
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet())  {
        if (s.contains(entry.getKey())) {
            form.setField(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an solution using streams:

```
for (String s : mass ) {  
    Optional<String> key = map.keySet().parallelStream().filter(s::contains).findFirst();
    if(key.isPresent()) {
        form.setField(key.get(), map.get(key.get()));
    }
}
```

The idea is to filter the map for every string adn check if there is a key which is contained in the current string.